# Handling new features in classification models

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I’m taking my first steps in ML, specifically with classifiers for text sentiment analysis. My approach is to make the usual 80% train dataset and 20% test. Having a trained model what is the best way to proceed in a production environment when new features appear (new words in texts not present in the initial dataset)?

Answer (score 0):

In classification task, all feature must be seen at train time and new features can not be add to prediction phase later. For your problem you can use, Stemming or Lemmatizing . Or Something like LDA or Word2Vec with large number of document they trained

this chapter could be useful: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are describing is generally known as "out of vocabulary" (OOV) words that appear in the test set but not in the training set. A traditional approach is to represent each OOV word with a special token, such as "UNKNOWN", and actually have those in the training data. This approach is discussed more fully in [Section 4.3](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/4.pdf) of "Speech and Language Processing" by Jurafsky and Martin.

A more modern approach is to use Word2Vec. This is a really [advanced topic](https://medium.com/cisco-emerge/creating-semantic-representations-of-out-of-vocabulary-words-for-common-nlp-tasks-842dbdafba18) that's found in neural networks.